# * is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio

I've got a problem with one of my web forms pages.

this is how it started.
I needed to completely revamp a page, I renamed the old pages default.aspx.vb.old and default.aspx.old and created brand new default.aspx and default.aspx.vb pages

every time I add a control to the aspx page and try and reference it in the code behind, I get the error `'lblError' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level`

**Page decalaration**

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="VB" MasterPageFile="~/_Masters/Principle.master" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="Default.aspx.vb" Inherits="Magazine_Default" EnableViewState="false" %>
```

**Label control in Default.aspx**

```
<asp:Label ID="lblError" runat="server" CssClass="cError" Visible="false" />
```

**Default.aspx.vb Code Behind**

```
Partial Class Magazine_Default
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    lblError.Text = "There was a problem retrieving the magazines, please try again later"
    End Sub
End Class
```

the page works, but visual studio will not build because it insists there is an error.

I thought it might be something up with my visual studio, like cache or something, so i nuked any temp files relating to the project.

and this morning a colleague did a git pull and has the same problem, errors are there, refuses to build but the page works.

The project itself is a website project, so there's no designer files where I can change the access modifier of the control.

I have also tried creating a new file, using the web form scaffolding that visual studio provides through `add->web form`, which has all the correct page directives in the .aspx and correct class declarations in the .aspx.vb, and it still does it.

There is also no red squiggly line under `lblError.Text`

When I create a new page in the different folder, it doesn't happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you renamed old default.aspx page, you need to rename its class too. Generally when you rename aspx page, it will not rename class name automatically. So you need to do that manually.

So for default.aspx page,

```
Inherits="Magazine_Default_Old"
```

And for default.aspx.vb page,

```
Partial Class Magazine_Default_Old
```

This will solve issue.

Comment: sorry i forgot to mention, after i renamed and copied across the stuff i need, i deleted the old files

Comment: If so, just restart visual studio, and open project again. There should not be any issues.

Comment: There was another file in a random place in the project inheriting magazine_default, so i guess the original had deleted had a different class name